# Apply css to a range of elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some html elements between two divs. What i want is to apply a css class to that range.
e.g

```
<div id=start_marker display:none></div>
<h1>some content</h1>
<div>child1</div>
<div>child2</div>
<div id=end_marker display:none></div>
```

So basically i have a div with `id=start_marker` and and end div with `id=end_marker` and there are bunch of other html elements between them.

I have set the display=none for both the start and end div as they just represents my start and end boundry and i dont want them on the page.

What i want, is to apply a css class (to do some highlighting) on the content between start and end div.

**Note: I cant wrap this in a div because that causes some issues in the layout and breaks some css.** I am not sure if there is any other html element i can add as container so as to apply css to that container without breaking the layout of inner children.

So far i have been able to get the elements i want using range in javascript. e.g something like this.

```
const startingDiv = dom.getElement("start_marker");
const endingDiv = dom.getElement("end_marker");
if (startingDiv && endingDiv) {
  let range = new Range();
  range.setStartAfter(startingDiv);
  range.setEndBefore(endingDiv);
  //todo: how to apply css to the range.
}
```

However i am not sure how to apply the css to this range. How to do this or is there any other way to achieve what i am trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could probably do this with CSS’s [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator). Something like:

```css
#start_marker ~ *:not(#end_marker ~ *) {
  /* ...highlighting rules… */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One implementation that I can currently think of is using the `nextElementSibling` property to loop over the elements within the range. Probably CSS alone might solve your problem as well but for curiosity sake, following should work for you :-

```js
const startingDiv = document.getElementById("start_marker");
const endingDiv = document.getElementById("end_marker");

function setClassForRange(startingEle,endingEle,className){
let temp = startingEle;
while(temp.nextElementSibling !== endingEle){
let currentElement = temp.nextElementSibling;
currentElement.classList.add(className);
temp = temp.nextElementSibling;
}
}

setClassForRange(startingDiv,endingDiv,'rangeCSS');
```

```css
.rangeCSS{
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>before range</div>
<div id=start_marker display:none></div>
<h1>some content</h1>
<div>child1</div>
<div>child2</div>
<div id=end_marker display:none></div>
<div> after range </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the divs, then use a for loop to loop through and style them

```
<div id="start_marker" style="display:none"></div>
<h1>some content</h1>
<div class="styler">child1</div>
<div class="styler">child2</div>
<div id="end_marker" "display:none"></div>
```

```
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('styler')
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].style.display = 'none' // replace with css you want to add
}
```

Comment: I cant add css to child elements within the two markers. Not in my control.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use css to target these elements.
If that's applicable to your problem.

- CSS general sibling selector `~` (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)
- and negation `:not()` (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)

should do the trick.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div>not affected before</div>
        <div id="start_marker" display:none></div>
        <h1>some content</h1>
        <div>child1</div>
        <div>child2</div>
        <div id="end_marker" display:none></div>
        <div>not affected after</div>
    </body>
    <style>
        :is(#start_marker ~ *):not(#end_marker ~ *)  {
            color: darkseagreen;
        }
    </style>   
    </html>
```

I do however recommend to schedule some refactoring with a proper css layout, because problems like yours (even if solved for now) tend to cause havoc somewhere down the line.

HTH, Cheers